# Optional binding irrespective of generic type

Tags: swift, generics, swift2, option-type

Consider the following code snippets:

Generic web wrapper view controller definition:

```
class WebWrapperViewController<T where T: UIView, T: WebViewCommon>: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

var loginUrl: NSURL!
var webView: T!
// ...
}
```

Code in the AppDelegate:

```
var webWrapperVC: UIViewController

if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
      webWrapperVC = WebWrapperViewController<WKWebView>()
} else {
      webWrapperVC = WebWrapperViewController<UIWebView>()
}

if let wvc = webWrapperVC as? WebWrapperViewController { // compiler error
       // don't care what generic type of WebWrapperViewController was created in here
       wvc.loginUrl = NSURL(string: "https://foo")
}
```

I get the following compiler error on the optional binding:

> Argument for generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

I don't care what type of generic version of `WebWrapperViewController` has been created, so I don't want to make the cast any more specific.

**Does anyone know how to wildcard the cast to any generic type?**

I've tried:

```
if let wvc = webWrapperVC as? WebWrapperViewController<AnyObject>
```

...along with a bunch of other things inside the angle brackets, including `<UIView>`, `<*>`, `<T>`. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to solve this is to use a protocol where all `UIViews` conform to instead of a generic class since casting with generics is not fully supported:

```
protocol UIViewType {
    var view: UIView { get }
}

extension UIView: UIViewType {
    var view: UIView { return self }
}

// the variable
var webView: protocol<UIViewType, WebViewCommon>
```

Use the view property to access UIView specific functionality.

Another way would be to make a failable initializer which takes a `WebWrapperViewController` and fails if the generic type cannot be casted:

```
class WebWrapperViewController<T where T: UIView, T: WebViewCommon>: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var loginUrl: NSURL!
    var webView: T!

    init?<U>(wwvc: WebWrapperViewController<U>) {
        // assign all variables
        if let webView = wwvc.webView as? T {
            self.webView = webView
        } else {
            return nil
        }
        loginUrl = wwvc.loginUrl
    }
}

// Now you can use it like this
if let wvc = WebWrapperViewController<AnyObject>(wwvc: webWrapperVC) {
       wvc.loginUrl = NSURL(string: "https://foo")
}
```